# Heroku rake db:seed permission denied when opening .xls with spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, heroku

I have been using the spreadsheet gem from http://spreadsheet.ch/ to read in seed data to a Rails 3 application.

I was using

```
Spreadsheet.open "xxxx"
```

which ran fine on my dev machine but when pushed to Heroku errored with "Permission denied"

The guide http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html is only very basic help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down we go into the 'long series of debugging questions' rabbit hole:

"Is the spreadsheet checked into git, such that it would show up on Heroku?"

"Is ruby spreadsheet trying to write to a file that's in one of the [read only](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) parts of heroku?"

"Are you using Spreadsheet.open  or ?"

I guess in general it would be nice if you could include a stack trace of the error Heroku is giving you.

Perhaps: `heroku logs` within your project directory might be of help, if the errors are recorded there?

Comment: Thanks for you response Tim. I will try to provide more info in my initial post in the future but you did send me in the right direction so giving you props for **"Is ruby spreadsheet trying to write to a file that's in one of the read only parts of heroku?"**

Answer (score 0):

Chalk this one up to **duh**

Spreadsheet by default opens in read/write which Heroku does not allow. A little ri research revealed that `Spreadsheet.open` can be passed the `'r'` flag for read-only. Here is the ri output

```
>>ri Spreadsheet.open
Spreadsheet.open

(from gem spreadsheet-0.6.5.4)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
open(io_or_path, mode="rb+", &block)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parses a Spreadsheet Document and returns a Workbook object. At present, only Excel-Documents can be read.
```